# Should I remove the ipv6 of my server from trusted IPs of fail2ban v0.9?

Tags: ipv6, fail2ban

I have new Plesk Onyx server with CentOS 7. I installed the Fail2ban component (the version installed is v0.9.6).

In the fail2ban.log I see a lot of warnings like this:

`WARNING Unable to find a corresponding IP address for xxxx:xxxx:x:xxxx::: [Errno -9] Address family for hostname not supported`

The ipv6 is the one of my server and I noticed that is in the trusted IPs list. I know that fail2ban v0.9 does not support ipv6.

Should I remove the ipv6 of my server from the trusted IP addresses to avoid these warnings? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Install a current version of fail2ban. v0.9.6 is several years old; v0.10 was released in July 2017, and includes support for IPv6.